# How to interface Google Go with Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, testing, go, interface

I'm trying to write a JavaScript test suite in Go.

I envision creating unit tests with Go, and running them against a Web application loaded in browser.

I've put a `test` JavaScript object into the global namespace for this purpose; so, I have a "hook" into the different components that I want to test.

Is it possible to load this script in Chrome, and expose the interface to `test` such that I can access in-browser JavaScript functions from Go?

Example:

// JavaScript function

```
// Intentionally, and cautiously, emplace "test" into the global namespace
// In practice I would make this a singleton :^D
test = (typeof test == "undefined") ? {} : test;

// Employ the method invocation pattern to append "test" with function "cheesePrice()"
// ES6 fat arrow function
test.cheesePrice = (type) => {
    let p = 0;
    switch (type) {
        case "cheddar" : { p = 9.99; break; };
        case "swiss" : { p = 6.49; break; };
        case "gouda" : { p = 7.49; break; };
        default : { // throw; }
    }
    return p;
}

// Example call
test.cheesePrice("swiss"); //-> 6.49
```

Given the above, how can I within a Go script, invoke test.cheesePrice(), and receive the return value? Something like this (pseudocoded);

```
// Imagine here browserHook is an interface into Chrome
// Enabling us to invoke the method above
func getJsCheesePrice(cheeseType string) float32 {
    return browserHook.test.getPrice(cheeseType);
}
func main() {
    assert.Equal(getJsCheesePrice("cheddar"), 9.99);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding there isn't a way to interface with javascript functions within a compiled Go program. There is however a [Selenium webdriver client for Go here.](https://github.com/sourcegraph/go-selenium)

Note that this won't necessarily allow you to call javascript functions directly, but will give you an interface to a browser running the JS.